# Successively longer sums of consecutive Fibonacci numbers: pattern?

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

Consider the following:
$$\begin{align}
F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}&=F_n\\
F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}+F_{n-3}&=F_{n-1}+F_{n-1}\\
&=2F_{n-1}\\
F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}+F_{n-3}+F_{n-4}&=F_n+F_{n-2}\\
&=L_{n-1}\\
F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}+F_{n-3}+F_{n-4}+F_{n-5}&=F_{n-1}+L_{n-2}\\
&=F_{n-1}+F_{n-1}+F_{n-3}\\
&=2F_{n-1}+F_{n-3}\\
F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}+F_{n-3}+F_{n-4}+F_{n-5}+F_{n-6}&=2(F_{n-1}+F_{n-4})
\end{align}$$
Is there some logic to this pattern? Can it be predicted? Is there a formula that can be used to compute the value of
$$\sum_{i=1}^{r}{F_{n-i}}$$
in terms of **only Fibonacci and Lucas numbers or their multiples, no constant terms,** without resorting to a summation?

Comment: Big hint: if $\mathcal{F}_n = \sum_{i=1}^nF_i$, then your sum is $\mathcal{F}_{n-1}-\mathcal{F}_{n-r+1}$.  Now, you should be able to find a formula for $\mathcal{F}_n$...

Comment: Sorry, @StevenStadnicki, this is NOT a homework question. Feel free to give an answer.

Comment: How do you get $F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}+F_{n-3}+F_{n-4}+F_{n-5}=2F_n$?

Comment: @BrianJ.Fink I didn't figure it was homework!  But it's also pretty easy and (IMHO) pretty fun to figure out for yourself.

Comment: @Steve I guess the constant will cancel out in that case.

Comment: Your edit didn't help. Additionally, in your very last lines you wrote $F_n+ F_{n+1}=F_{n+1}$...?

Comment: There, @draks..., I fixed it. Did I make any other mistakes?

Comment: @draks..., Lucas numbers follow the rule $L_n=F_{n+1}+F_{n-1}$.

Comment: If you rewrite every one of these results, on the right-hand side, as the appropriate $$ A F_n + B L_n,  $$ you should get an understandable pattern in how $A,B$ change depending on the number of terms summed. I think you can avoid rational coefficients (as opposed to integers only) by switching to  $$ A F_{n-1} + B L_{n-1}.  $$

Comment: @draks... On closer inspection, there does appear to be an error in my $2F_n$ result, but I'm having difficulty spotting where I made it.

Comment: @draks... I found the error. I will complete my edits at another time. Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: @Steve there was a slight error in your hint, but I appreciate that you pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the formula that I found in [this question,](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243606/induction-proof-formula-for-sum-of-n-fibonacci-numbers) I have derived the following:
$$\begin{align}
f(n,r)&=\sum_{i=1}^r{F_{n-i}}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}{F_i}-\sum_{i=1}^{n-r-1}{F_i}\\
&=F_{n-1+2}-1-F_{n-r-1+2}+1\\
&=F_{n+1}-F_{n-r+1}\\
\\
f(8,6)&=F_{8+1}-F_{8-6+1}\\
&=F_9-F_3\\
&=34-2\\
&=32\\
&=13+8+5+3+2+1\\
&=F_7+F_6+F_5+F_4+F_3+F_2\\
\\
f(7,3)&=F_8-F_5\\
&=21-5\\
&=16\\
&=8+5+3\\
&=F_6+F_5+F_4
\end{align}$$

So it turns out the solution is the difference of two Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: I wouldn't have posted my answer if I had known that while I was working on it, someone else had already answered my question. Sigh.

Comment: It's good that you posted an answer, the poster might have preferred an induction based approach rather than a linear algebra based approach.

Comment: @DanielV, I _am_ the poster! LOL

Answer (score 3):

$$F_n = \left(\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}^n\right)_{2,1}$$

which let's us treat it like any other summation except using matrices instead of scalar numbers, just remember that matrix multiplication doesn't commute and everything else is the same.

Using $X = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $I = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, proceed:

$$\begin{align}
S &= \sum_{i=1}^r F_{n - i} \\
  &= \left(\sum_{i=1}^r X^{n-i}\right)_{2,1}\\
  &= \left(\sum_{i=n - r}^{n - 1} X^i\right)_{2,1} \\
  &= \left(X^{n - r}
     \underbrace{\sum_{i=0}^{r - 1} X^i}
     _\text{Q = Geometric Series}
     \right)_{2,1}\\
\end{align}$$

Geometric series,

$$\begin{align}
Q &= \sum_{i=0}^{r - 1} X^i\\
  &= \left(X^{r} - I\right)
     \left(X     - I\right)^{-1}\\
  &= \left(X^{r} - I\right)
     X\\
  &= X^{r+1} - X
\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}
S &= \left(X^{n - r}\right)
     \left(X^{r+1} - X\right)_{2,1}\\
  &= \left(X^{n+1} - X^{n+1-r}\right)_{2,1}\\
  &= F_{n + 1} - F_{n + 1 - r}
\end{align}$$

Comment: That's all very nice, but I arrived at the same solution without all that linear algebra.

Comment: @BrianJ.Fink and of course, with significantly more modesty!

Comment: Sorry, I had no idea that anyone had answered my question when I answered it.

Comment: @BrianJ.Fink I like seeing different approaches to the same question, and appreciate you answering as well.  One of the great things about the study of mathematics, how different people can solve a problem different ways, but as long as there is no mistake, always arrive at the same answer.